# Change Paginator Sort template CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use **CakePHP 3** Paginator Sort inside a `<option>` `HTML` tag but this output a link inside the `value` atributte like this:

**`<option>` whith paginator inside `value` atributte:**

```
<select name="products-order" class="form-control products-order inline-pagination-menu" onchange="redirect(this)">
    <option value="<?= $this->Paginator->sort('product_name') ?>">A - Z</option>
    <option value="<?= $this->Paginator->sort('product_name', null, ['direction' => 'desc']) ?>">Z - A</option>
    <option value="<?= $this->Paginator->sort('price') ?>">Menor preço</option>
    <option value="<?= $this->Paginator->sort('price', null, ['direction' => 'desc']) ?>">Maior preço</option>
</select>
```

**The output**

```
<select name="products-order" class="form-control products-order inline-pagination-menu" onchange="redirect(this)">
    <option value="<a href="/posts/index?page=1&amp;sort=user_id&amp;direction=asc">User Id</a>">A - Z</option>
</select>
```

I try to change the Template but this didn't worked (Is throwed: call undefined method in `$this->Paginator->templates`) What I try below:

**Put this in action (method in clontroller):**

```
public $helpers = [
    'Paginator' => ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']
];
```

**and change the template:**

```
$this->Paginator->templates([
    'sort' => '{{url}}'
]);
```

**Paginate full code**

```
        $this->paginate = [
            'conditions' => ['product_name LIKE' => '%' . $search . '%'],
            'maxLimit' => 10,
            'contain' => ['Medias' => function($q){
                return $q->select(['path', 'product_id'])
                    ->where(['media_type_id' => 3]);
            }]
        ];

        $this->Paginator->templates([
            'sort' => '{{url}}'
        ]);
        $products = $this->paginate($this->Products);
```

**Error:**

```
2015-12-14 15:31:47 Error: Fatal Error (1): Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent::templates() in [C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\src\Controller\ProductsController.php, line 121]
Trace:
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::handleFatalError() - CORE\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php, line 192
Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler::Cake\Error\{closure}() - CORE\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php, line 91
[main] - [internal], line ??



2015-12-14 15:31:47 Error: [Cake\Error\FatalErrorException] Call to undefined method Cake\Controller\Component\PaginatorComponent::templates()
Request URL: /products/search?search=a
Stack Trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PROJETOS\Shopping\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Error\BaseErrorHandler.php(91): Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->handleFatalError(1, 'Call to undefin...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 121)
#1 [internal function]: Cake\Error\BaseErrorHandler->Cake\Error\{closure}()
#2 {main}
```

Comment: When receiving errors, please always post the _complete_, _exact_ error message, and include the corresponding stacktrace (ideally from the logs, where it is formatted properly)! Also you should mention where the code is placed that you are howing here, the first snippet is in the controller, and the second one?

Comment: @ndm I put thepaginator code and error from log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paginator *component* has no `templates()` method, hence the error. It's the paginator *helper* that supplies such a method, which can be used to change the templates.

From the controller context, there's only the `templates` option that can be passed in the `$helpers` variable, as already shown in your code snippet. However this is ment to be used for loading templates from external files!

You seem to have copied that snippet from the docs, read what the text underneath the sample says:

> This will load the file located at **config/paginator-templates.php**. See the example below for how the file should look like.
>
> [...]
>
> Whether your templates are in the primary application or a plugin, your templates file should look something like:
>
> ```
> return [
>     'number' => '<a href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a>',
> ];
> ```

Long story short, either use the option and put the templates in the proper file as described, or put the `templates()` call snippet in your view template.

Also you should be aware that there are more sort related templates:

- `sort`
- `sortAsc`
- `sortDesc`
- `sortAscLocked`
- `sortDescLocked`

so be sure that you overwrite all that are necessary.

See also **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Paginator > PaginatorHelper Templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#paginatorhelper-templates)**

Comment: ndm I create the file in config folder with the exactly content in your answer, put `public $helpers = [
    'Paginator' => ['templates' => 'paginator-templates']
];` in my ProductsController and the error persist

Comment: @Ricardo The exact content would be wrong, as you don't want to change the `number` template, but the `sort*` ones. The error will persist if you keep the wrong `templates()` call in your controller.

Comment: Sorry ndm, I change the number to sort before but the error persist

Comment: @Ricardo Because this has nothing to do with each other, as I said, the error stems from the incorrect `templates()` call, so remove it. If at all, it would have to go in the corresponding actions view template.

Comment: ndm I remove and sometimes works sometimes not, I will update my questions with the error description

Comment: @Ricardo That's a totally different problem, and should go into a new question where you can describe it in detail.